# Why can’t i get a result for gasStation better?

Tags: java

I’m new with java, and my compiler doesn’t tell me what the errors are for this code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        class gasStation {

            double price;
            double distance;
        }
        gasStation shell = new gasStation();
        shell.price = 2.72;
        shell.distance = 1.25;
        gasStation exxon = new gasStation();
        exxon.price = 2.35;
        exxon.distance = 1.75;
        class betterDeal {

            public gasStation compare(gasStation shell, gasStation exxon) {
                double shellRating = shell.price * shell.distance;
                double exxonRating = exxon.price * exxon.distance;
                if (shellRating > exxonRating) {
                    gasStation better = shell;
                } else if (shellRating < exxonRating) {
                    gasStation better = exxon;
                }
                return better;
            }

            System.out.println (better);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please format your code. Also what is your question? *`Why can’t i get a result for gasStation better?`* doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: You're trying to put classes inside the main. This is incorrect. If I were you I would refer to the javadoc tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: Your returning better but not calling the compare method and storing the returns result

Comment: Why cant i print the object ‘better’ at the end of my code. Im sorry im a complete newb

Comment: @user10635007 As I said you are trying to put everything inside of your main. You need to create the classes separate, and then construct the objects in the main and call the methods on the objects

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code.

- Initialize the variable `better` outside the `if` scope.

  ```
  gasStation better = null;
  if (shellRating > exxonRating) {
      better = shell;
  } else if (shellRating < exxonRating) {
      better = exxon;
  }
  return better;
  ```
- All the statements should be either inside a method or a block. Put your `System.out.println(better);` statement inside the `compare` method, before the return statement.

  ```
  public gasStation compare(gasStation shell, gasStation exxon) {
      double shellRating = shell.price * shell.distance;
      double exxonRating = exxon.price * exxon.distance;

      gasStation better = null;
      if (shellRating > exxonRating) {
          better = shell;
      } else if (shellRating < exxonRating) {
          better = exxon;
      }
      System.out.println(better);
      return better;
  }
  ```
- You can get your `gasStation` class and `betterDeal` class out of the `Main` class.
- *Why can't I print the object ‘better’ at the end of my code?* That's because you never call the `compare` method. Create a new object of the `betterDeal` class and call the `compare` method inside your `main` method to print the variable `better`.

  ```
  new betterDeal().compare(shell, exxon);
  ```
- But still if you need to print the `price` and the `distance` of the `better` variable you'll have to override the `toString()` method inside the `gasStation` class.

  ```
  class gasStation {

      double price;
      double distance;

      public String toString() {
          return "Price: " + price + "\nDistance: " + distance;
      }
  }
  ```

---

Full Code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        gasStation shell = new gasStation();
        shell.price = 2.72;
        shell.distance = 1.25;
        gasStation exxon = new gasStation();
        exxon.price = 2.35;
        exxon.distance = 1.75;

        new betterDeal().compare(shell, exxon);
    }

}

class gasStation {

    double price;
    double distance;

    public String toString() {
        return "Price: " + price + "\nDistance: " + distance;
    }
}

class betterDeal {

    public gasStation compare(gasStation shell, gasStation exxon) {
        double shellRating = shell.price * shell.distance;
        double exxonRating = exxon.price * exxon.distance;

        gasStation better = null;
        if (shellRating > exxonRating) {
            better = shell;
        } else if (shellRating < exxonRating) {
            better = exxon;
        }
        System.out.println(better);
        return better;
    }

}
```

Comment: It definitely does. I've updated my answer. Observe the mistakes. Check the full code.

Comment: @user10635007 It prints the better price and the distance. Change the `toString()` method on your will.